# How much of Vedanta Desikan's Ahara Niyamam is based on Ayurveda or shares similarities with it?

Tags: food, gunas, ayurveda, vedanta-desika, sattvik

*Ahara Niyamam* means "Dietary restrictions", and Vedanta Desikan [wrote a work with the same name](https://www.srivaishnavam.com/desikaprabandam/ahara_meaning.htm) that shows what food items are appropriate and inappropriate for Sri Vaishnavas based on the foods' sattva component.

Since Ayurveda also recognizes the three gunas concept, how much of Vedanta Desikan's Ahara Niyamam is based on the Ayurveda, or shares similarities with it? One rule in Ahara Niyamam is, "do not consume curd at night", which is also mentioned by Ayurveda as krama viruddha (order incompatibility). So what else is based on Ayurveda or is also found in Ayurveda?

Desikan referenced many scriptures including the Ramayana when compiling the Ahara Niyamam, so did he also reference Ayurvedic texts?